# How to add period at the end of the output? DSA

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Recently got a DSA Interview Question which is as follow :
Q1 - Given 5 elements i.e 1,2,3,4,5 print all possible unique combination for _ _ _ [3 blanks spaces] [Simple Permutation Question]

Follow up of Q1 - Now present output as follows

```
1 2 3 , 1 2 4 , 1 2 5 , 1 3 2 , 1 3 4 , 1 3 5 , 1 4 2 , 1 4 3 , 1 4 5 , 1 5 2 , 1 5 3 , 1 5 4 , 2 1 3 , 2 1 4 , 2 1 5 , 2 3 1 , 2 3 4 , 2 3 5 , 2 4 1 , 2 4 3 , 2 4 5 , 2 5 1 , 2 5 3 , 2 5 4 , 3 1 2 , 3 1 4 , 3 1 5 , 3 2 1 , 3 2 4 , 3 2 5 , 3 4 1 , 3 4 2 , 3 4 5 , 3 5 1 , 3 5 2 , 3 5 4 , 4 1 2 , 4 1 3 , 4 1 5 , 4 2 1 , 4 2 3 , 4 2 5 , 4 3 1 , 4 3 2 , 4 3 5 , 4 5 1 , 4 5 2 , 4 5 3 , 5 1 2 , 5 1 3 , 5 1 4 , 5 2 1 , 5 2 3 , 5 2 4 , 5 3 1 , 5 3 2 , 5 3 4 , 5 4 1 , 5 4 2 , 5 4 3 .
```

> [Note last symbol has to be a period and not comma]

How to come up with the solution?
I am stuck at this

```
class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    
    for(int i = 1 ; i<6 ; i++){
      for(int j = 1 ; j<6 ; j++){
        for(int k = 1 ; k<6 ; k++){
            if( !(i == j || i == k || j==k )){ // No repetition allowed 
              System.out.print(i+" "+j+" "+k+" , ");
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } 
  }
```

Also , open to new or different solution but very curious if there is way to solve the problem with existing code which I have provided.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this, including building a list of permutations and outputting them, or joining them with `String.join`, or adding an if statement to check if you're at the end to print a period instead of a comma, or building a string and slicing off the last comma and replacing it with a period. What have you thought of and where are you stuck specifically with what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last "," character and the space that follows it, and add a ".".

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
            for (int k = 1; k < 6; k++) {
                if (!(i == j || i == k || j == k)) { // No repetition allowed
                    stringBuilder.append(i + " " + j + " " + k + " , ");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    stringBuilder.delete(stringBuilder.lastIndexOf(","), stringBuilder.length());
    stringBuilder.append(".");
    System.out.print(stringBuilder.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some googling would help you study the topic. Here's one article I found that may help you in your quest.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-combinations-algorithm

Also be careful with the math meanings of the word combination vs. permutation. In permutation, the order does matter.

i.e. 1,2,3 and 3,2,1 are two different permutations. But the same combination.